# Specified key was too long for unique keys: laravel migrations

Tags: php, laravel, migration

I am programming a project with laravel 5.6 and have a little problem in migrations

when I run `php artisan migrate:fresh` I get an error :

```
Migrating: 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table

   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` ad
d unique `users_username_unique`(`username`))
```

codes :

```
// 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
    if (!Schema::hasTable('users')) {
                Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
                    $table->string('name');
                    $table->string('username')->unique();
                    $table->string('email')->unique();
                    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
                    $table->string('password');
                    $table->rememberToken();
                    $table->timestamps();
                });
            }
```

> Used technologies: **laravel 5.6**, **composer 1.8**

Comment: It is laravel 5.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message implies, the unique key is too long for the DB.

You can name your unique indices in Laravel migrations like so:

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    $table->string('name');
    $table->string('username');
    $table->string('email');
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->unique('username', 'username');
    $table->unique('email', 'email');
});
```

This way your unique index for `username` will be named `username` instead of `users_username_unique` and so, will not exceed the byte limit for the index name